# How to set max_retries to unlimited on an OracleAQ queue

Tags: oracle, queue, jms, message-queue, oracle-aq

I have set up a queue in OracleAQ.  If I understand the settings correctly this configuration will try each hour for 168 hours before removing the message:

```
 EXEC dbms_aqadm.create_queue(queue_name=>'MYT_INFO_QUEUE',queue_table=>'MY_QUEUE_TABLE',max_retries=>168,retry_delay=>60,retention_time=>3600);
```

How can I set the max_retries to unlimited?  It seems that a value of 0 will never retry, and I didn't see any documentation as to how to set to unlimited.  Is there a way, or do I need to just use a large number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no unlimited possible for the max_retries

> The maximum value of max_retries is
>   2**31 -1.

[Refer This](http://www.di.unipi.it/~ghelli/didattica/bdldoc/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/aq_admin.htm)